# How can I create a SimpleDB instance for testing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I have an Amazon account to access SimpleDB and other AWS services. Whilst I can spin up new servers etc there only seems to be one SimpleDB instances associated with my account.

Is it possible to devote another SimpleDB instance to testing, and maybe another to staging, without registering multiple Amazon accounts?

Comment: I think you can create a multiple instance of `SimpleDB` with the same `AWS Account`. You can create a specify testing  `Amazon SimpleDB Domain` and can use that `domain` only for `testing`. `AWS Identity and Access Management` is also help you `Create users and groups` under your `AWS account` but still all the `users` will share common `resources` like `domain`. FYI: `SimpleDB` is Like `Database` and `Domain` is like `Table` in `traditional database`. So I am trying to say here is `Create` a `Table` say `Testing` and use that `Table` ONLY for testing.

Comment: Thanks, I know I can create multiple domains, but I'd like to keep my test domains separate from my production ones without having to prepend "test_" to all their names.